# Axios request works only on second request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am building a user login system and currently the way I have it set up, the user types in their email and password and then that information is sent to my server to be checked if accurate. If it is, I create a JWT token and send it back along with the mongodb _id of the user, I then in another request use the mongodb _id of the user from the first request to retrieve all the information (blogs in this case) associated with their mognodb _id. All of this works except for the issue I am running into is the axios request does not work the first time. So I have to hit submit to log in for an error to occur `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')` and then when I hit submit again it works. I believe the problem is `getBasic` not getting set before the rest of the code runs on the first attempt, and on the second attempt it is already defined. I am not sure how I can fix this without maybe a manual timer before I do the `getBasic.data.map`, but I know there must be a better way to fix this.

And just to add this is just me trying to test this concept so I understand later things like bcrypt will need to be added to the password instead of plaintext in the database, etc.

Frontend:

```
 function Login() {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()

    const [Item, setItem] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    async function fetchData() {
        const sentItem = {
            user: user.data.user._id,
        }

        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api', sentItem)
            .then(result => setGetBasic(result))
    }



    const loginFunc = async () => {
        const checkUser = {
            email: Item.email,
            password: Item.password
        }

        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/login', checkUser)
            .then(result => setUser(result))
            .then(fetchData())  
    }







    if (user && getBasic) {

        localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(user.data.token))
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('key'))

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="email" value={Item.email} placeholder="email" />
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="password" value={Item.password} placeholder="password" />
                    <button onClick={loginFunc}>Submit</button>

                </div>


                {
                    getBasic.data.map(({ text, _id, }, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <p>{_id}</p>
                                <p>{text}</p>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }   
        )
    }
    return (

        <div>

            <input onChange={handleChange} name="email" value={Item.email} placeholder="email" />
            <input onChange={handleChange} name="password" value={Item.password} placeholder="password" />
            <button onClick={loginFunc}>Submit</button>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Server:

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {


    const user1 = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password })

    if (user1) {
        const payload = { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email };
        const token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, { expiresIn: '200s' });
        console.log('correct login')
        res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: true, user: user1 })

    } else {
        console.log('incorrect login')
    }

})


app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {

    Blog.find({ user: req.body.user }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(result)
        }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While nature of `React.useState` is asynchronous, and changes will not be reflected immediately, closures take their role in situations like this, as pointed out in link in below.

More details provided here - [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

As stated in error from your example, cannot read `data` of undefined - meaning `user` is undefined, and you try to access to `user.data` which leads to error.

```
const sentItem = {
    user: user.data.user._id,
}
```

Instead of

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/login', checkUser)
            .then(result => setUser(result))
            .then(fetchData())
```

why don't you try this (remove fetchData function if not reused on other places...):

```
const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/login', checkUser);
const sentItem = {
   user: result.data.user._id,
}
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api', sentItem)
        .then(result => setGetBasic(result));

setUser(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create user state like this

`const [user, setUser] = useState({})`

Comment: Can I get an explanation why, I got the answer to my question from another response already but would like to understand this comment.

Comment: because we should add a default state

Comment: what ab for `const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()`?

Comment: i think it should also be a object because you are passing json object as a result

Answer (score 0):

`.then(fetchData())`

The `then` method accepts a function which runs when the other stuff is done.  However, you are not passing in a function here, but the return result from calling fetchData.

Try
`.then(fetchData)`

or

`.then(() => fetchData())`